# jQuery: Select Images That are Linking to Image Files

Tags: jquery, image

How can I select images that are wrapped in  tags under the condition that the  tag href is to a gif, jpg, png, bmp, or some other image file type.

The reason I want to select these images is to add the overlay text "Click to Enlarge" to each image.

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
$('a[href$=".gif"], a[href$=".jpg"], a[href$=".png"], a[href$=".bmp"]').children('img');
```

The above selector is not case sensitive though, you might be better off selecting all links with images in them and filtering through them manually, like @reporter suggested.

Comment: For images query query parameters after the filename, you can use `a[href*=".jpg"]` for example.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you want;

```
$("img");
```

This will select all images on the page.

```
$("img[src$='.gif']");
```

This selects all GIF files (assuming the url ends with .gif)

```
$("img[src$='.gif'], img[src$='.png']");
```

This selects all GIF and PNG files.

```
$("img.thumb");
```

And finally this one will select all images with the 'thumb' class.

Answer (score 1):

```
    //find all images
    $("#YourContainerTag").find("img").each(function()
    {
      //read the parent
      var parentLinkObject = $(this).parent();
      if (parentLinkObject.name == "a")
      {
        //read the attribute 'href'
        hrefAttribute = $(parentLinkObject).attr("href");
        //look for graphical file types
        ...     
      }
     //what ever you want to do
     ...
    });
```

Comment: good answer but you can simplify this really simply in jquery. $("a[href$='.jpg']").children('img') for example.

Comment: yeah If I saw the other answers I realized how huge my lack of practise in jquery is. I hope that I will get more chances for coding in jquery again.

Comment: Check out http://jsfiddle.net/  it's a great place to practice JQuery (and other frameworks) for questions like this!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just select all `<img />` elements.  If you need something else, you should provide an example or list of the elements and what you need selected.

```
$('img');
```